# runtime exception while inserting to hive orc partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive

when i am trying to insert data to a hive orc partitioned table, i am getting the below runtime exception .the query is nothing but a simple insert from a text hive partitioned table.both the source and target tables are partitioned

```
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:565) at 

org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:83) ... 17 more 

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method) at 
        org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.DynamicByteArray.add(DynamicByteArray.java:115) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.StringRedBlackTree.addNewKey(StringRedBlackTree.java:48) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.StringRedBlackTree.add(StringRedBlackTree.java:55) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl$StringTreeWriter.write(WriterImpl.java:1218) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl$StructTreeWriter.write(WriterImpl.java:1743) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.addRow(WriterImpl.java:2412) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.write(OrcOutputFormat.java:86) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:764) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:841) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:88) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:841) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:133) at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:170) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:555) ... 18 more ]],
     Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:8, 
    Vertex vertex_1540158411191_10651_2_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due 
    to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 
    killedVertices:0 (state=08S01,code=2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you use `tez`? how about without `tez` (i.e. usual MR) ?

Comment: yes i am running through  tez engine

Comment: if you use `tez` you probably need some Hive upgrade or patch to support the erroneous query. again, try running without `tez` to be sure that it is the reason

Answer (score 0):

Run all these commands and try inserting now.

```
**hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true**
**hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = strict**
**hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode = 100**
**hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions = 1000**
**hive.exec.max.created.files = 100000**
**hive.error.on.empty.partition = false**
```